# How to put images into theme from server folder (not from media library)

Tags: images

I'm trying to put image files into an images folder inside my theme, and display them on the page, but I'm getting the broken image icon. When I copy the file location from the server folder and try it in the browser there is no image there.

Is it possible to display images that aren't in the media library (just from a folder in your theme folder) on WordPress, and is there some special way to do it?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

hammered it out.

Anyone else with this question, try `<img src="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/images/yourimagename.jpg">`

Comment: Please accept your own answer